# Prefix files with same names inside multiple directories and copy them into another directory

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have 50 files stored in 50 directories
eg

```
d:\RAWFILES\AK\shape.geojson
d:\RAWFILES\AL\shape.geojson
d:\RAWFILES\AR\shape.geojson
```

I want all the files to be renamed as AK_shape.geojson , AL_shape.geojson and copied to 1 directory above
ie. in

```
d:\RAWFILES\AK_shape.geojson
d:\RAWFILES\AL_shape.geojson
d:\RAWFILES\AR_shape.geojson
```

I have tried this and not succeded :

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name "shape.geojson" -exec bash -c ' DIR=$( dirname "{}"  ); echo "{}" "$DIR"/"${DIR##*/}".geojson' \;

FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share a [mcve] of your coding attempts! You have not got any? Well, then you should, and you should read [ask]…

Comment: I have tried a bit of powershell, can you please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simpler (and *much* faster) Batch file do it:

```
@echo off
cd d:\RAWFILES
for /D %%d in (*) do move "%%d\shape.geojson" "%%d_shape.geojson"
```

Comment: Simple and Perfect Solution, solved my issue...thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this -

```
$PathRoot = "d:\RAWFILES\"
foreach($item in (Get-ChildItem $PathRoot))
{
    $Prefix = $item.name
    Get-ChildItem $PathRoot\$Prefix | % {Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $Prefix"_"$_}
    Get-ChildItem $PathRoot\$Prefix | Move-Item -Destination $($PathRoot)
}
```

Comment: Okay, so i am getting this error :   Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'D:\WY_shape.geojson' because it does not exist.
At line:5 char:5
+     Get-ChildItem $PathRoot\$Prefix | Move-Item -Destination $PathRoo ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\WY_shape.geojson:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: Yes because the correct path would be `D:\RAWFILES\WY_shape.geojson`. I have updated the code. Can you give it a try now.

Comment: now the code is not working, and its also not throwing any error

Comment: Can you use a [try-catch block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.1) and let me know the error that you are getting cause I am not able to replicate your error.